# Наследование в php, доступ к переменным через $this в родительском классе

Tags: php

Почему метод getLevel() в дочернем класе ListenLevel возвращает переменную $this->level, но родительский класс Level возвращает NULL если перенести метод getLevel() в него.

```
<?php

namespace learnukrainian\models;
use learnukrainian\models\Level;

class ListenLevel extends Level
{
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->level = $user->getUserListenLevel();
        $this->exercise_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }

    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    /**
     * @return string - current level
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'ListenLevel' . $this->level;
    }
}

<?php
namespace learnukrainian\models;

use learnukrainian\models\ListenLevel;
use learnukrainian\models\ReadLevel;
use learnukrainian\models\WriteLevel;

class Level
{
    private $level;
    private $exercise_ids;


    public function getExercises()
    {
        $exercises_ids = $this->exercise_ids;
        $exercises = [];

        foreach ($exercises_ids as $id)
        {
            $exercises[] = new Exercise($id);
        }

        return $exercises;
    }
}
```

Comment: Но в родительском классе ты не присваиваешь переменной никакого значения?

Comment: Разве в PHP область видимости переменной `private` выходит за сам класс? Вот [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php) на решение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в родительском классе это свойство приватное:

```
private $level;
```

А значит имеет своё собственное значение отличное от одноимённого в дочернем классе. Но в дочернем в это свойство хотябы присваивается значение. В родительском никакого значения нет и взяться ему не откуда.

Comment: дело было действительно в доступе к переменной. Если в родительском классе private то что об этом знает дочерний? Ничего.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что класс `ListenLevel` расширяет `Level`, но это не значит что тут ведется работа с одним классом.

Даже не знаю как доступно объяснить, но попробую: Когда создается класс `ListenLevel` он в свое пространство включает(добавляет) то что у тебя в `Level`, как-бы создает все для себя. При этом класс `Level` - это отдельный класс, со своим пространством. У этих Классов нет никакой связи между собой.

На примере:

```
class A {
    public $a;
    public $с = 1;
}
class B {
    public $b;
    public $с = 2;
}
```

Если `B` расширить `A`, то грубо говоря у вас по факту получается класс `C`:

```
//class B extends A - создаст третий класс:
class C {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $с = 2;
}
```

P.S. В случае дубликатов, как вы можете видеть, будут использованы дочерние.

P.S.2. Вам чтобы проверить что у вас в классе `Level` придется создавать его новый экземпляр, а он не связан с экземпляром `ListenLevel`.